# HAProxy on Amazon EC2 instance type

Tags: amazon-ec2, haproxy

I am setting up load balancing for my Amazon RDS Read Replicas using HAProxy, should I use a m1.large or c1.medium instance type for running HAProxy ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into Elasticache.

If you are determined to use HAProxy then I'd select the instance with a higher memory level when load balancing read replicas.

Are you going to run a cluster of HAProxy so that this is not a single point of failure?